# Django staticfiles not loading

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-staticfiles

I am using s3 to serve my static files. The files are present on the s3 bucket but when i run my website those files do not load up. I have installed django-storages and boto3 for this.
This is what is see [Click Here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7J3A.png)

when i inspect the image i can see that the image url is pointing towards the s3 aws bucket but for some reason the css and images are not being shown on the website itself.
here is my setting.py

```
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'home',
    'accounts',
    'blog',
    'tinymce',
    'storages',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/media')

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = ''
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = ''
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = ''

AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'ap-south-1'
AWS_SIGNATURE_VERSION = 's3v4'

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels': 20,
    'selector': 'textarea',
    'theme': 'silver',
    'plugins': '''
            textcolor save link image media preview codesample contextmenu
            table code lists fullscreen  insertdatetime  nonbreaking
            contextmenu directionality searchreplace wordcount visualblocks
            visualchars code fullscreen autolink lists  charmap print  hr
            anchor pagebreak
            ''',
    'toolbar1': '''
            fullscreen preview bold italic underline | fontselect,
            fontsizeselect  | forecolor backcolor | alignleft alignright |
            aligncenter alignjustify | indent outdent | bullist numlist table |
            | link image media | codesample |
            ''',
    'toolbar2': '''
            visualblocks visualchars |
            charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor |  code |
            ''',
    'contextmenu': 'formats | link image',
    'menubar': True,
    'statusbar': True,
}






EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
```

Comment: Do you have the access key, secret and bucket name set ? If yes, you may need to configure your S3 bucket to allow requests from your server.

Comment: i have set the access key and secret key by creating a new user giving him the permissions

Comment: the link of the image that i can see is https://vedicmiracles-staticfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/Image/logo.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIASFF7NV6BDU62DBB4%2F20201225%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20201225T182755Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=2487e1259b2236eed264b11ad7f541590bfec826143162c730af21aad55d80d7

Answer (score 0):

**settings.py**

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME'
S3DIRECT_REGION = 'S3DIRECT_REGION'
S3_URL = '//%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_URL = '//%s.s3.amazonaws.com/media/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_URL
```

Also, run the below command from the command line in the project root.

```
python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
```